# Using Thymeleaf with Google charts and Java Map

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, google-visualization, thymeleaf

The Thymeleaf block I have made in JavaScript cuts off the ending ; of the variable, and throws an `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2`.

The code does parse like it should, except for the data variable. Parsed code:

```
function drawChart() {

    var jsonData = "{ 'cols': [" +
        "{'id':'','label':'Expense','pattern':'','type':'string'}" +
        "{'id':'','label':'Amount','pattern':'','type':'number'}]," +
        "'rows': [";

    var data = {'Expense1': 25.0, 'Expense2': 20.0, 'Expense3': 40.0};
    var end = "]}";
    var res = jsonData.concat(data);
    var res = res.concat(end);

    var json = JSON.parse(res);

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);

    var options = {
        title: 'Data test',
        pieHole: 0.4
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Pre Thymeleaf code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var jsonData = "{ 'cols': [" +
            "{'id':'','label':'Expense','pattern':'','type':'string'}" +
            "{'id':'','label':'Amount','pattern':'','type':'number'}]," +
            "'rows': [";

        var data = /*[[${chart.DataPoints}]]*/;
        var end = "]}";
        var res = jsonData.concat(data);
        var res = res.concat(end);

        var json = JSON.parse(res);

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);

        var options = {
            title: /*[[${chart.title}]]*/'',
            pieHole: 0.4
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

The data var is either like it is right now, or when enclosed in "", it cuts off the closing semi-colon. How do I get Thymeleaf of JavaScript to cast the data var to a string (while maintaining the '' it contains)?

Comment: Are you using thymeleaf 3? Print and validate JOSN  being returned from {chart.DataPoints}

Comment: I am using thymeleaf 2 unfortunately.

Comment: What's the output of /*[[${chart.DataPoints}]]*/;

Comment: {'Expense1':25.0,'Expense2':20.0,'Expense3':40.0}

Comment: Can you try var json = JSON.parse(res.replace(/\\/g, ""));

Comment: create:33 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at drawChart (create:33)
    at <anonymous>

It seems like for some reason Thymeleaf only wants to output raw data, and I can't convert it to a string because of the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?  I don't think you need to build your data as a JSON string first, simply create it as a JavaScript object:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var json = {
            'cols': [
                {'id':'', 'label': 'Expense', 'pattern': '', 'type': 'string'},
                {'id':'', 'label': 'Amount', 'pattern': '', 'type': 'number'}
            ],
            rows: []
        };

        var data = /*[[${chart.DataPoints}]]*/ [];
        var rows = [];
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
            rows.push({
                "c": [
                    {"v": key,       "f": null},
                    {"v": data[key], "f": null}
                ]
            });
        });

        json['rows'] = rows;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
        var title = /*[[${chart.title}]]*/ '';
        var options = {
            title: title,
            pieHole: 0.4
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

- edit: you can format the data however you want... it's pretty trivial to do in JavaScript.

Comment: This does render the title of the chart, but does displays "no data" where the graph should be, looking into the JSON at the moment.

Comment: {"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Expense","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Amount","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":{"Expense1:25,"Expense2":20,"Expense3":40}} it does output valid JSON, I think there have to be square brackets around 'rows' though, I feel like it's getting close.

Comment: I changed the JSON to hardcoded JSON. Is there a way to format the /*[[${chart.DataPoints}]]*/ to something like this:
{"c":[{"v":"Expense1","f":null},{"v":25,"f":null}]},
                    {"c":[{"v":"Expense2","f":null},{"v":20,"f":null}]},
                    {"c":[{"v":"Expense3","f":null},{"v":40,"f":null}]}?